# How to download Chrome on TeamCity CI server?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there any way we can download the chrome browser for TeamCity? I have tried to download Chrome in my CI server using `selenium-standalone` plugin but that didn't seem to work for me. When I tried to install it, I SEEM to be successful installing `firefox` , but `chrome` doesn't seem to work.

```
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] ----------
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] selenium-standalone installation starting
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] ----------
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] 
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] ---
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] selenium install:
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] from: https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] to: /home/centos/Agent2/work/ab85ea71c0c1d72c/CPQ/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/3.0.1-server.jar
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] ---
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] chrome install:
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] from: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.28/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] to: /home/centos/Agent2/work/ab85ea71c0c1d72c/CPQ/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.28-x64-chromedriver
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] ---
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] firefox install:
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] from: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.13.0/geckodriver-v0.13.0-linux64.tar.gz
[18:49:37][Step 1/8] to: /home/centos/Agent2/work/ab85ea71c0c1d72c/CPQ/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/geckodriver/0.13.0-x64-geckodriver
[18:49:38][Step 1/8] /home/centos/Agent2/work/ab85ea71c0c1d72c/CPQ/node_modules/selenium-standalone/bin/selenium-standalone:105
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]         throw err;
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]         ^
[18:49:38][Step 1/8] 
[18:49:38][Step 1/8] Error: Could not download https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.28/chromedriver_linux64.zip: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/centos/Agent2/work/ab85ea71c0c1d72c/CPQ/node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/install.js:286:12)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at Request.g (events.js:291:16)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at Request.onRequestError (/home/centos/Agent2/work/ab85ea71c0c1d72c/CPQ/node_modules/request/request.js:845:8)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at ClientRequest.onConnect (/home/centos/Agent2/work/ab85ea71c0c1d72c/CPQ/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:167:23)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
[18:49:38][Step 1/8]     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
```

When trying to run `wct` which invokes selenium-standalone, I get an error saying

```
 Error: The following browsers were not found: firefox, chrome. (All installed browsers found: )
```

Any help would be appreciated to install `chrome` OR `firefox` on TeamCity. Thanks!